# Proving that orthonormal set is an orthonormal basis

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, orthogonality

If I know that the set of functions $\{\phi_n\}_1^\infty$ forms an orthonormal basis on $L^2(a,b)$ and the set $\{\psi_n\}_1^\infty$ is an orthonormal set on $L^2(\frac{a-d}{c}, \frac{b-d}{c})$, with $c>0, d\in \mathbb{R}$ and it is given that:

$$\psi_n(x) = \sqrt{c}\;\phi_n(cx+d),$$

then how do I prove that the set $\{\psi_n\}_1^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis on $L^2(\frac{a-d}{c}, \frac{b-d}{c})$?

I am given that if $f\in L^2(a,b)$ and the set $\{\phi_n\}_1^\infty$ forms an orthonormal basis on $L^2(a,b)$, then

$$||f||^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left| \langle f, \phi_n \rangle \right|^2= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left| \int_a^bf(x)\overline{\phi_n(x)}\;dx \right|^2\;\;\;\;\text{(by Parseval's equation)}.$$

How do I prove in the case of $\{\psi_n\}_1^\infty$ that if $f\in L^2(\frac{a-d}{c}, \frac{b-d}{c})$, then

$$||f||^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left| \langle f, \psi_n \rangle \right|^2= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left| \int_{\frac{a-d}{c}}^{\frac{b-d}{c}}f(x)\overline{\psi_n(x)}\;dx \right|^2?$$

**UPDATE**:

Should I use the following to prove this:

Let $\{\textbf{u}_1, ..., \textbf{u}_k\}$ be an orthonormal set of $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{C}^k$. For any $\textbf{a} \in \mathbb{C}^k$ we have:

$$||\textbf{a}||^2 = |\langle \textbf{a}, \textbf{u}_1\rangle|^2 + \cdots |\langle \textbf{a}, \textbf{u}_k\rangle|^2.$$

Is it sufficient to use this theorem in the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**:

You goal is to prove that  $\{\psi_n\}_1^\infty$ is a linearly independent and spanning family.

Why is it already linearly independent ?

For the spanning property, consider $f \in L^2(\frac{a-d}{c}, \frac{b-d}{c})$

What can you say about $f(cx+d)$ ?

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help @GabrielR. =) The set of functions $\{\psi_n\}_1^{\infty}$ is linearly independent, because $\langle \psi_n, \psi_m\rangle$ equals $1$, when $n=m$ and $0$, when $n\neq m$. The input values for $f(cx+d)$, get mapped into the interval $[a,b]$? =)

Comment: @jjepsuomi Yes, it's alright.

Comment: +1 Thank you @GabrielR. One last question, is it okay to use the theorem I posted as update in my post? Is it an sufficient answer? =) If I let $k\rightarrow \infty$? =)

Comment: @jjepsuomi I don't think it's a good idea. Letting $k \to \infty$ raises convergence issues.